# How to load an image stored in a byte array to WebView?

Tags: android, webview, arrays

everyone! I have compressed lots of pictures to a "pictures.zip" file. I want to load one of these pictures to a WebView like this:

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<img src=\"abc.jpg\">", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Here,"abc.jpg" is a picture that has been compressed to pictures.zip file.

1. **I just want to decompress the picture from the zip file and get
   the picture's byte stream, and then
   load the image to the WebView from
   the byte stream.**
2. I don't want to decompress the
   picture from the zip file and then
   save it to sdcard and then load it.
3. Moreover, I don't want to encode the
   pitcture's byte to a base64 and then
   load the image to the WebView
   either, because these two ways will
   be very slow.

Comment: @user549380: First, why do you need to use a WebView? Second, your logic isn't right here - using "<img src=\"abc.jpg\">" implies reference to a 'file' of some sort local or otherwise. As far as I've read so far, you can't create 'in-memory' files with android and if you could, I don't see how a WebView could access them.

Comment: A famous software called "mdict" can load image from its resource file(.mdd file) without storing the image into harddrive. And it just use html like <img src="abc.jpg"> to load abc.jpg which is compressed to a .mdd file.

Comment: Show an example of how mdict uses <img src="abc.jpg"> and it might explain things further.

Comment: By [Overriding webviewClient][1] you can achieve this but it requires android level 10+


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780899/intercept-and-override-http-requests-from-webview

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no way to have all three of these requirements. Base64 encoding it and loading it into the image tag directly is probably your best bet if you don't want to write it to storage, although you can still write it to internal storage and show it in a webview.

```
private static final String HTML_FORMAT = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,%1$s\" />";

private static void openJpeg(WebView web, byte[] image)
{
    String b64Image = Base64.encode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String html = String.format(HTML_FORMAT, b64Image);
    web.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Comment: I would like to note that you could shorten this further (an probably increase performance) by giving loadData() the base64 directly;

`String b64Image = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);`
`web.loadData(b64Image, "image/jpeg", "base64");`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using embeddable HTTP listener within your application where listen to specific port (for instance 8001), then in your HTML Page reference images to your listener. For example looking for Test.png would be something like:

http://localhost:8001/Test.png

This request will end up in your listener where you can look into your zip file or database and then return byte stream to HTTP Response stream!

I really recommend you to take a look at NanoHTTPD (http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/) and try to implement custom serve method for your goal.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: this is good option for some situations but accessing http://localhost is another headache it doesnt work like PC