# Using Android WebView to load external HTML with local resources (images, javascript)?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to create a simple web based application on Android that loads certain large files, like Javascript and user interface elements locally, from 'assets' directory. However I am unable to use local assets directory when loading external HTML. So the external server would give something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/javascript.js"/>
```

And WebView would use that, even if the website itself came from external website. I know there are security risks involved, but is there a way to perhaps do that by only allowing specific URL's on applications end?

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all you have to copy all the assets somewhere (external storage, for instance).

Then, to filter URL's you should override method

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url);
```

in WebViewClient class.

added:
When your application starts, put the assets to /sdcard/somefolder/ see [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

in shouldOverrideUrlLoading override url to something like this

```
file:///sdcard/somefolder/<your filename here>
```

it should be as easy as

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   url = "file://" + context.getExternalFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + url;
   super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}
```

Comment: This does not actually work, did you test it? Android does not execute shouldOverrideUrlLoading() when it loads resources (like pictures and JavaScript). There is a method for interrupting this loading process called shouldInterceptRequest(), but it is available only on Android API 11 and above and I need it for Android 2.2 (API 8 and above).

Comment: Try this method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Think this post is about the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780899/intercept-and-override-http-requests-from-webview

Basically api lvl 11 supports it, anything prior is just screwed :)

Comment: does not work. Your override of shouldOverrideUrlLoading does nothing.