# Intercept resource requests from WebView in API 9

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to intercept resource requests from a WebView in order to provide previously downloaded resources (pre-caching). There is [a method for this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) in API 11+, but I need to support Gingerbread.

Does anyone have a good idea for accomplishing this?

So far I've thought about using [addJavascriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) and some JS injected into the page to asynchronously provide resources, but that is pretty messy since I don't have control of the web content being displayed and would have to use regex to modify the image tags etc.

This has been asked before, almost, but neither thread contains a good solution for this scenario. ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833597/intercept-and-update-javascript-from-webview)) ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780899/intercept-and-override-http-requests-from-webview))

Comment: are you trying to precache images?

Comment: Images and javascript and css, yeah.

Comment: where are the resources? sdcard? assets?

Comment: I'm meaning to store them in my app's external storage space in a cache the app would manage itself. So usually this would be somewhere on the sdcard.